# Class com.hadoop.compression.lzo.LzoCodec not found for Spark on CDH 5?

Tags: apache-spark, cloudera-cdh, hadoop-lzo

I have been working on this problem for two days and still have not find the way.

**Problem**: Our Spark installed via newest CDH 5 always complains about the lost of LzoCodec class, even after I install the HADOOP_LZO through Parcels in cloudera manager. **We are running MR1 on CDH 5.0.0-1.cdh5.0.0.p0.47**.

**Try to fix**:
The configurations in [official CDH documentation about 'Using the LZO Parcel](https://www.cloudera.com/content/cloudera-content/cloudera-docs/CM4Ent/4.7.3/Cloudera-Manager-Installation-Guide/cmig_install_LZO_Compression.html)' are also added but the problem is still there.

Most of the googled posts give similar advices to the above. I also suspect that the spark is trying to run against YARN that is not activated there; but I can not find the configuration in CMF or other posts about this topic.

Please give me some help if you know how to deal with it.

Answer (score 29):

Solved!! May the solution help others who encounter the same problem.

---

In this tutorial, I will show you how to enable LZO compression on Hadoop, Pig
and Spark. I suppose that you have set up a basic hadoop installation
successfully (if not, please refer to other tutorials for [Hadoop installation](http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/stable/)
).

You reach this page possibly because you encounter the same problem
as I encountered, usually starting with Java exception:

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Class com.hadoop.compression.lzo.LzoCodec not found.
```

As the Apache and Cloudera distributions are two of the most popular
distributions, configurations for both contexts are shown. Briefly, three
main steps would be walked through towards the final success:

- Installing `native-lzo` libraries
- Installing `hadoop-lzo` library
- Setting up environment variables correctly (the right part
  consuming my most time)

### Step1: Installing `native-lzo` libraries

The [native-lzo library](http://www.oberhumer.com/opensource/lzo/) is
required for the installation of `hadoop-lzo`. You can install them manually
or by facilitating the Package Manager (**NOTE:** Make sure all nodes in the
cluster have `native-lzo` installed.):

- On Mac OS:

  ```
  sudo port install lzop lzo2
  ```
- On RH or CentOS:

  ```
  sudo yum install lzo liblzo-devel
  ```
- On Debian or ubuntu:

  ```
  sudo apt-get install liblzo2-dev
  ```

### Step2: Installing `hadoop-lzo` library

#### For Apache Hadoop

As the LZO is GPL'ed, it not shipped with official Hadoop distribution which
takes Apache Software License. I recommend the [Twitter version](https://github.com/twitter/hadoop-lzo) which is a forked version of
[hadoop-gpl-compression](https://code.google.com/a/apache-extras.org/p/hadoop-gpl-compression>) with
remarkable improvements. If you are running the official Hadoop, some
installation structures are provided the [the documentation](https://github.com/twitter/hadoop-lzo/blob/master/README.md>).

#### For Cloudera Distribution

In Cloudera's CDH, `hadoop-lzo` is shipped to customers as parcels and you
can download and distribute it conviniently using the Cloudera Manager. By
default, the `hadoop-lzo` will be installed in
`/opt/cloudera/parcels/HADOOP_LZO`.

Here we show the configuration on our cluster:

- Cloudera CDH 5
- HADOOP_LZO version 0.4.15

### Step3: Setting up env variables

#### For Apache Hadoop/Pig

The basic configuration is for Apache Hadoop, while Pig is piggying upon its
functionality.

- Set compression codecs libraries in `core-site.xml`:

  ```
  <property>
    <name>io.compression.codecs</name>
    <value>org.apache.hadoop.io.compress.GzipCodec,
        org.apache.hadoop.io.compress.DefaultCodec,
        org.apache.hadoop.io.compress.BZip2Codec,
        com.hadoop.compression.lzo.LzoCodec,
        com.hadoop.compression.lzo.LzopCodec
    </value>
  </property>
  <property>
    <name>io.compression.codec.lzo.class</name>
    <value>com.hadoop.compression.lzo.LzoCodec</value>
  </property>
  ```
- Set MapReduce compression configuration in `mapred-site.xml`:

  ```
  <property>
    <name>mapred.compress.map.output</name>
    <value>true</value>
  </property>
  <property>
    <name>mapred.map.output.compression.codec</name>
    <value>com.hadoop.compression.lzo.LzoCodec</value>
  </property>
  <property>
    <name>mapred.child.env</name>
    <value>JAVA_LIBRARY_PATH=$JAVA_LIBRARY_PATH:/path/to/your/hadoop-lzo/libs/native</value>
  </property>
  ```
- Append `HADOOP_CLASSPATH` to `hadoop-env.sh`:

  ```
  HADOOP_CLASSPATH=$HADOOP_CLASSPATH:/opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH/lib/hadoop/lib/*
  ```

#### For Cloudera Distribution

You can use the Cloudera Manager to enable the same previous settings via GUI
interface:

- For MapReduce component, change the configuration of corresponding keys as
  above:

  ```
  > **io.compression.codecs**
  > **mapred.compress.map.output**
  > **mapred.map.output.compression.codec**
  > **MapReduce Client safety valve for mapred-site.xml**
  ```
- Edit **MapReduce Client Environment Snippet for hadoop-env.sh** to append the
  `HADOOP_CLASSPATH` variable.

At last, restart dependent services in right order and deploy the
configurations among all nodes. That's it!!. Then you can test the
functionality with command and get successful messages similar to below:

```
   $ hadoop jar /path/to/hadoop-lzo.jar com.hadoop.compression.lzo.LzoIndexer lzo_logs
   $ 14/05/04 01:13:13 INFO lzo.GPLNativeCodeLoader: Loaded native gpl library
   $ 14/05/04 01:13:13 INFO lzo.LzoCodec: Successfully loaded & initialized native-lzo library [hadoop-lzo rev 49753b4b5a029410c3bd91278c360c2241328387]
   $ 14/05/04 01:13:14 INFO lzo.LzoIndexer: [INDEX] LZO Indexing file datasets/lzo_logs size 0.00 GB...
   $ 14/05/04 01:13:14 INFO Configuration.deprecation: hadoop.native.lib is deprecated. Instead, use io.native.lib.available
   $ 14/05/04 01:13:14 INFO lzo.LzoIndexer: Completed LZO Indexing in 0.39 seconds (0.02 MB/s).  Index size is 0.01 KB.
```

#### For Spark

This consumes me much time because there are less information in previous
posts. But the solution is strightforward with previous experience.

No matter the Spark is installed via tar or the Cloudera Manager, you need
merely to append two path values to `spark-env.sh`:

```
   SPARK_LIBRARY_PATH=$SPARK_LIBRARY_PATH:/path/to/your/hadoop-lzo/libs/native
   SPARK_CLASSPATH=$SPARK_CLASSPATH:/path/to/your/hadoop-lzo/java/libs
```

### Ralated posts and questions

A comparison of LZO performance is given in [another place](http://blog.cloudera.com/blog/2009/11/hadoop-at-twitter-part-1-splittable-lzo-compression/). A
related question is also asked on [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23441142/1320284) but there are no solutions
about this up to the finish of this tutorial. You maybe also interested in how
to [use the LZO Parcel from Cloudera](http://www.cloudera.com/content/cloudera-content/cloudera-docs/CM4Ent/latest/Cloudera-Manager-Installation-Guide/cmig_install_LZO_Compression.html).

Comment: It would be valuable to include the information here on SO so that it will persist should your blog go down or change address.

Comment: @ChrisF sorry, the link is updated now after a migration of my blog to github.

Comment: @caesar0301 - it would also be helpful if you summarised the answer here. Then it will survive future migrations.

Comment: the link is broken again

Comment: Link "Twitter Version" is 404

Comment: SPARK_LIBRARY_PATH has been changed in 2014, via: https://github.com/apache/spark/commit/fb98488fc8e68cc84f6e0750fd4e9e29029879d2, *Removes the shipping of SPARK_CLASSPATH, SPARK_JAVA_OPTS, and SPARK_LIBRARY_PATH to the executors on the cluster. This was an ugly hack. Instead it introduces config variables spark.executor.extraJavaOpts, spark.executor.extraLibraryPath, and spark.executor.extraClassPath.*

Answer (score 1):

For Hortonworks 2.3.0 with Ambari for Spark to work with LZO you need to add **Custom spark-defaults** properties.  I added:

- spark.driver.extraClassPath `/usr/hdp/current/hadoop-client/lib/hadoop-lzo-0.6.0.{{hdp_full_version}}.jar`
- spark.driver.extraLibraryPath `/usr/hdp/current/hadoop-client/lib/native:/usr/hdp/current/hadoop-client/lib/native/Linux-amd64-64`

This is based on the [HDP 2.3.0 upgrading SPARK 2.2](http://docs.hortonworks.com/HDPDocuments/HDP2/HDP-2.3.0/bk_upgrading_hdp_manually/content/upgrade-spark-22.html) page (it has some typos).

Comment: If running spark via command line,same properties(as pointed out by dajobe) can also be passed as parameter to the spark cli in the following format:
spark-submit --conf spark.driver.extraClassPath=<path to hadoop lzo jar>:<path to hadoop-4mc jar> --conf spark.driver.extraLibraryPath=/usr/hdp/current/hadoop-client/lib/native:/usr/hdp/current/hadoop-client/lib/native/Linux-amd64-64

Answer (score 0):

I just had the same error in my Cloudera 5 installation. In my case it was GPLEXTRAS parcel which was installed, distributed but not activated.

On Cloudera Manager -> Hosts -> Parcels
I pressed on filters clear everywhere, then I was able to press the Activate on the GPLEXTRAS parcess that was previously distributed already.

That was enough to fix my issue.

Answer (score 0):

`Class com.hadoop.compression.lzo.LzoCodec not found` hadoops to me too ,when I query hive whith emr.

Given others's solutions ,I take a shor-cut.
in core-site.xml

delete this:

```xml
<property>
  <name>io.compression.codec.lzo.class</name>
  <value>com.hadoop.compression.lzo.LzoCodec</value>
</property>
```

and delete  `com.hadoop.compression.lzo.LzoCodec,com.hadoop.compression.lzo.LzopCodec` in this:

```xml
<property>
  <name>io.compression.codecs</name>
  <value>com.hadoop.compression.lzo.LzoCodec,com.hadoop.compression.lzo.LzopCodec,org.apache.hadoop.io.compress.DefaultCodec,org.apache.hadoop.io.compress.GzipCodec,org.apache.hadoop.io.compress.BZip2Codec,org.apache.hadoop.io.compress.DeflateCodec,org.apache.hadoop.io.compress.SnappyCodec,org.apache.hadoop.io.compress.Lz4Codec</value>
</property>
<property>
```